# Creating files in all subfolders of a file with a bat file

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a folder with lots of subfolders and I want to create a folder in each of these subfolders. As There is a lot of these folders I was wondering if there was a way of automatically doing this with a bat file.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer][1] on SuperUser will help.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/359392/add-a-new-folder-to-each-subfolder

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your problem
FOR /d %A IN (d:\softwares\files*) DO mkdir %A\source

Comment: This fails on folders with space etc

Comment: sry i didn't check that out

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the folder in question: it works on all subfolders in the tree.

If you only want to process the immediate set of folders then remove the `/s`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad ') do md "%%a\folder" 2>nul
echo done
pause
```